# Build the geometric structure of SnBr2

Tags: covalent-compounds, molecular-structure

What is Sn valence in this case? Because  it depends on it if it will be linear or tetragonal.I'm talking about a molecule.

Comment: Clarify, if you are talking about a molecule, a water solution or a solid state.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the gas phase (molecular), SnBr2 is bent with an angle of 95 degrees.

The IUPAC definition of valence is such that there is only one valence for each element.

Valence is independent of the compound being consider.